# Unit testing : ViewController has no segue with identifier : "segue id"

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ios6, gh-unit

I want to test below method :

```
- (void)myMethod
{
    self.contact = nil;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue id" sender:self];
}
```

This is what I do in test class :

```
- (void)testMyMethod
{
    // Call method to test
    [testClass myMethod];

    // Tests
    GHAssertNil(testClass.contact, @"contact should be nil.");
}
```

Running the test gives me error :

```
Reason : Receiver (<RS_MainViewController:0x126b6330>) has no segue with identifier 'segue id'
```

Why I get this error and what is the solution?

Comment: Have you specified segue id for that segue in the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I had to load the view controller from the storyboard in my test and then it worked. The I was able to call `viewDidLoad` in my tests and continue.

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController* controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewControllerId"];
AAAMyViewController* viewController = (AAAMyViewController*)controller;
```

I also had to go into the storyboard and add a Storyboard ID for this view controller (MyViewControllerId).